# Programs running on Hyper-V with Invoke-Command hang

Tags: powershell, windows-10, hyper-v, invoke-command

I'm trying to run my software on Hyper-V VM using powershell Invoke-Command, without success. Host OS -Windows 10. Guest OS - also Windows 10. VM Generation 1.

I did some simple experiments and found out this:

If I run

```
Invoke-Command -VMName MY_VM -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock { calc }
```

then I can see launched calc.exe on the guest system right with UI.

But if I run mspaint or any non-Microsoft program, nothing happens. The program just hangs in the VM TaskManager without any effect.

I also tried to run several different programs using CLI calling Invoke-Command several ways, but got the same result.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer is that powershell remote connections (or any remote connection like rdp, ssh, etc) take place in a separate logon session, and can't really interact with each other.

There are two reasonable ways to do this:

1. Use PsExec - part of the [microsoft sysinternals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) tools group.

```
# List sessions - note the session ID of the session you want the process to start in
quser /server:$computername
# Run a process remotely, specifying the logon ID
PsExec.exe -s -i $ID notepad.exe
```

2. Use a scheduled task that runs when you are logged in and is visible. You can do this with powershell's various `New-ScheduledTask` commands to create one, or follow [this guide](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-remotely-start-an-interactive-process/) by Scripting Guy! using WMI `Win32_ScheduledJob` methods.

See [use powershell to start a gui program on a remote machine](https://serverfault.com/questions/690852/use-powershell-to-start-a-gui-program-on-a-remote-machine/852877) for more details on both options, and a well-written description of why it's hard to do in windows.

Comment: "...remote connections (or any remote connection like rdp, ssh, etc) take place in a separate logon session, and can't really interact with each other" Seems reasonable, but then why do I see the calc.exe UI in that case?

Comment: @Alex ah I missed that part of your question. The short answer is windows store apps / appx packages are handled a lot differently by the OS than normal applications. Things like calculator/paint 3d/maps run in a separate 'layer' sandboxed from each other, and bind to the windows session with a UI running. I'm not as familiar with these apps so I don't have a more technical explanation, but I hope it helps.